# Should I do anything about questions that are attracting (IMO) unnecesary flags?

Tags: discussion

I just dove into the LQP Review Queue today (hooray, I hit 2000 unicorn points!), and I noticed that the first three flags I handled were all on answers to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28199310/2615940). Some of them did indeed have syntax errors, but they were all very clearly attempts to answer the question. It's my understanding that a post being wrong is not the criteria for flagging a question as a LQP, so I marked them as "Looks OK".

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is my understanding of the LQP flag correct? I've been flagging for a long time and have a good track record of my flags not being declined, so I like to think I'm good on this point.
2. Is there anything I should do when I notice that a particular question seems to be getting an unusual number of bad flags?

Note: The proposed duplicate to this question suggests that my understanding of the LQP flag is correct, but the main point of my question is this: if I, as a reviewer, identify an pattern of incorrect flag usage, can I put a stop to the pattern to save other reviewers' time and how? If the flags all came from the same user, could a moderator see this and send the user a message reminding them of the correct usage of the LQP flag? Any other options?

Comment: I think that linked answer helps assure me that my understanding of the LQP flag is correct, but it doesn't address the other part of my question, so I don't think it's a duplicate. As a reviewer, is there any action I can or should take to  prevent further erroneous flags? Should I bring it to a moderator's attention? Can a moderator find out if the flags were all raised by the same person and send them a message reminding them of what the LQP flag is for?

Comment: the most natural thing to do would be to _flag_ these questions for mod attention complaining about unnecessary flags. Moderator probably wouldn't mind adding yet another decline to a piling heap :)

Comment: There's a good chance that those posts weren't flagged by a person, but rather by the system for just being so short and being code-only.  I forget where, but an SE employee basically stated that answers like these are pretty hard to distinguish automatically from lots of answers that really *are* NAA.  Removing these false positive would remove a lot of true positives too, and since we have actual human people in the queue to mark the false positives as "Looks Okay", it's not a problem.

Comment: Poor questions can attract poor answers. Comment on the answers that code without explanation is often poor. Consider rewording the question so that code only wont answer it. Possibly flag the answer as too broad too - there area dozen equally right ways to answer it currently.